# Equating interface with a class that implements it

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I have a problem with trying to equate an interface to a class that implements that class.

I have an interface called SortedSetADTx.java 
I have a class called BstSetKTUx.java

Now in the my main class I have two variables

```
private static SortedSetADTx<Automobilis> autoSet;
private static BstSetKTUx<Automobilis> autoSetBst;
```

and in one of my function I want to do this:

```
autoSet = new BstSetKTUx(new Automobilis());
autoSetBst = autoSet;
```

And I get an error that those two are incompatible types.
The reason I am doing that, I want to use a function that BstSetKTUx class has.
I hope you can understand my question, it's really hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted that `BstSetKTUx` implements `SortedSetADTx`, you can simply try this chunk of code:

```java
autoSet = new BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>(new Automobilis());
autoSetBst = (BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>) autoSet;
```

The major change I did here is a cast to `BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>`. Since we know that `autoSet` contains a `BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>` (see first line of my snippet), we can cast without having to check for `autoSet`'s class first.

If you happen to not know what `autoSet` contains before you try to cast to `BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>`, I recommend using the `instanceof` operator.

```java
// given we don't know if autoSet contains a BstSetKTUx instance or not
if(autoSet instanceof BstSetKTUx) {
    // we can cast to BstSetKTUx without any problems
    autoSetBst = (BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>) autoSet;
} else {
    // autoSet does not contain an instance of BstSetKTUx
}
```

Besides that, it's good programming practice that you always specify the type arguments of a class (`<Automobilis>`), even when you're calling a constructor. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try typecasting `autoset` since it isn't of type `BstSetKTUx`... you can only equate objects that are from the same class.
i.e. `autoSetBst = (BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>)autoset;`

Comment: Actually it'd be  autoSetBst = (BstSetKTUx<Automobilis>)autoset;

Comment: I attempted that a couple of times but it doesn't seem to show up. :/ I'm not so sure if it's because edits need approval or something.

Comment: Edits of own posts usually don't need approval. Let's see if I can do it.

Comment: Well, according to the edit page, your answer was already updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following variables:

```
SortedSetADTx<Automobilis> autoSet;
BstSetKTUx<Automobilis> autoSetBst;
```

Note that `autoSet` is of type `SortedSetADTx` but not `BstSetKTUx`. However, `autoSetBst` is of type `BstSetKTUx`, *and also* of type `SortedSetADTx`, since `BstSetKTUx` implements `SortedSetADTx`.
Therefore, you can't assign `autoSet` to `autoSetBst`, but you can do it the other way round:

```
autoSetBst = new BstSetKTUx(new Automobilis());
autoSet = autoSetBst;
```